# Passing argument in trigger dynamically

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER audit_proc_tr
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON "log".hi
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE "log".audit_proc(argument);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_configpurchaseorder(configpurchaseorder, xmode text, xuserno integer)
  RETURNS text AS

 END;
```

I want to pass `xmode` is a argument of `trigger`

Comment: I think you want the PL/PgSQL `EXECUTE` command, possibly as `EXECUTE ... USING` and/or with the `format` function. Details in the documentation.

Comment: @CraigRinger I think you wrongly understood the question. i want to pass that xMode in the trigger. For example, the function fn_configpurchaseorder(...,xmode text,...) will be called when ever i will do insert/delete/update, that xmode is just to identify about the process(insert/update/delete) that is going to occur. so assume if the fn_configpurchaseorder was called with xMode 'I', if so i will identify, 'oh this call is for insert', similarly after the table gets affected(ins/del/upd) the corresponding trigger will gets called,so in that trigger fn i need to identify the xMode to proceed.

Comment: Er ... do you mean the pre-defined `TG_OP` variable?

Comment: @CraigRinger yes sir I knew that. but in my case i don't want to use it. I just need to pass that parameter as i said before

Comment: Couldn't guess what you're really trying to do from this amount of info then. I'd advise you to elaborate.

Comment: You can pass arguments to a trigger, but they are string literals, and since they can only be defined at trigger creation, they can be thought as constants.  With these you can modify the trigger behaviour if you use the same procedure with multiple triggers, but (AFAIK) can't achieve anything which you can't achieve by using `TG_OP`, `TG_TABLE_NAME` and other variables.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass data to a trigger that is not provided by one of the predefined variables you could put that data in a temp table before you perform the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE that will fire the trigger. Then you can retrieve the data from the table inside the trigger function. Temp tables are local to sessions so this is safe to do when multiple clients connect to the same database.